# redirection of Site using js when first one won't load

Tags: javascript, java, html

there are two Sites like www.abc.com and www.abc1.com, if first site won't open in 30 seconds then its automatically redirect to second site using java script .can you help me  to build a code .i am a fresher .

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function that return true if the DOM is loaded or false if not.

```
function isDOMLoaded(){
  return document.readyState == 'complete';
}
```

then

```
if(isDOMLoaded == false){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "www.abc1.com";
    }, 30000);
}
```

But, if you have server errors (like errors with 500) ...I don't think you can do much!

Answer (score 1):

You can check if it is loaded in 30000 milliseconds, if it is not redirect.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.onload = function () { 
        var loaded = true;
    }
    if(!loaded){
        window.location.replace("http://abc1.com");
    }
}, 3000
);
```